# Saving outlook mail items in UTF-8 / Unicode using C#

Tags: unicode, utf-8, outlook, mailitem

We have created an Outlook Plugin which (amongst other things) can be used to save Mail items in text form to a specific folder. However, the text of the resulting text file is encoded in ANSI and I would like to save it as UTF8. I have already set the Codepage of the mail item like so:

```
mail = (MailItem)objItem;
mail.InternetCodepage = 65001; // equal UTF8 encoding; see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff860730.aspx
mail.SaveAs(filePath, olSaveAsType);
```

However, the resulting file is saved as "ANSI as UTF8" and all extended characters (e.g. in Arabic or Russian) come out as question marks. 
Does anyone know how I can save the mail item in utf8?

Thanks a lot.

Cheers,

Martin

Comment: As a workaround, I have now implemented this function myself, but it would still be interesting to know, if the Outlook API provides a "SaveAsUnicode" function out of the box.

Comment: What is your source store (PST, Exchange, etc.)? What is the Outlook version? Does it work if you save through the Outlook UI (File | Save As)?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to set the encoding, try reading `InternetCodepage` and then using a `System.Text.Encoding` object to read the saved file into a string. You could then convert and re-save the string as another file in the encoding you prefer.